# Help with issue installing software package openFOAM

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

Hello I tried installing OpenFOAM 4.0 on my computer that has Ubuntu 16.04, however during the installation I accidentally turned my computer off. how can I remove what has been installed so far so I can start again. I was following [the installation instructions](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Installation/Linux/OpenFOAM-4.0/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_16.04). I got to stage 10.2 where i needed to run `./Allwmake -j 4 > log.make 2>&1` for the first time but while it was executing I hit the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Just redo step 10.2 and continue with the remaining steps should do it.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work

Comment: Please update your question with the errors you get.